# PHPSESSID cookie lost after redirect

Tags: php, header

My website redirects user to the payment Gateway page. Once the user has completed the payment, they are redirected back to my website receipt page `process.php`. Please note that user redirects away from and return to https page. website URL is exactly the same i.e: user redirects away from https://website.com/payment.php to **Payment Gateway** and then back to https://website.com/process.php?para1=true&para2=true

```php
session_start();
print_r($_COOKIE);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

What i get is this:

```
    Array(
        [lang] => en
        [theme] => light
        [timezone] => Asia/Baghdad
    )
    Array(
    )
```

What I expect to get is this:

```
    Array(
        [lang] => en
        [theme] => light
        [timezone] => Asia/Baghdad
        [PHPSESSID] => 2b656f9120*********6fd1817316
    )
    Array(
        [nonce] => 68e56bb********f2253529e09bf3f
        [userID] => 1
        [last_error] => 
        [last_success] =>
    )
```

Things i've tried:

1. Failed to recreate issue by redirecting user to another website that i own and redirecting them back to `process.php`
2. Tried redirecting user landed on `process.php` again to `process.php`
3. On another tab when I refresh any other page on my website, the `PHPSESSID` comes back. Refreshing `process.php` after refreshing other page makes `PHPSESSID` to appear again.
4. This is only happening when the Payment Gateway redirects user back to my website. Redirecting from any other website using `header("Location: website.com/process.php")` does not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your apache config?

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict
```

Changing Strict to Lax should solve your issue:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Lax
```

See also https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/

Try changing the defaults for `session_start()`:

```
$secure = true; // if you only want to receive the cookie over HTTPS
$httponly = true; // prevent JavaScript access to session cookie
$samesite = 'lax';

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300) {
    session_set_cookie_params($maxlifetime, '/; samesite='.$samesite, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $secure, $httponly);
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params([
        'lifetime' => $maxlifetime,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'secure' => $secure,
        'httponly' => $httponly,
        'samesite' => $samesite
    ]);
}
```

See also https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#125072

Comment: Wont it make website vulnerable to CSFR attacks?

Comment: I guess it does exactly what you want: In "Lax" mode, some cross-site usage is allowed. Cookies are sent with cross-origin requests for link, prerender and get-requests even if they have a same-site attribute. This is in contrast to "Normal" where cookies are also send for image, iframe, ajax and post-requests. "Strict" would prevent any cookies with the same-site attribute from being send for a request where the domain in the URL changed.

Comment: See also https://owasp.org/www-community/SameSite "The lax value provides a reasonable balance between security and usability for websites that want to maintain user’s logged-in session after the user arrives from an external link."

Comment: See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html on how to prevent CSFR.

Comment: You've educated me in depth about issue i wasnt even aware of. Thank you so much @took this was really helpful.